my Model.create() in sequelize and node.js does not save data on mysql database
I working on creating a database using MySQL, express.js, and Sequelize. My model is saved on the database, but when I send data it will not work as expected.
Here is my code:
Database.js
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize("node-compelet", "root", "********", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: "localhost",
});
module.exports = sequelize;

and my Model called product.js
const sequelize = require("../util/database");
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const Product = sequelize.define("Product", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  price: { type: DataTypes.DOUBLE, allowNull: false },
  imgUrl: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  description: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
});
module.exports = Product;

and my controller :
const Product = require("../models/product")
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const imgUrl = req.body.imgUrl;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  console.log(req.body);
  Product.create({
    title: title,
    price: price,
    imgUrl: imgUrl,
    description: description,
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("result");
      res.redirect("/");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

And my app.js:
const sequelize = require("./util/database");
const Product = require("../models/product")
sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("synced secceed");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("faild");
  });

Whenever I tried sending data to the database nothing had happened and my web page continued loading. In addition, in the controller, I tried to log the received data, but it didn't work. I got no error message.  It seems that my model doesn't work properly.
I've checked the router and my functions are registered properly.

I'm not familiar w/ sequelize, but I see you're not calling next at any point. That's likely to cause hangs.

@CollinD only in case of an error as I see it. @zahra1996a you need to add something like next(err) at the end of catch handler

Generally, next is an "error-first callback". The first argument is an error, or falsy, and the second arg is some result. So next() would be expected where there's no error.

sorry I didn't mentioned that actually i'm using express.js . no the problem is not next.() . thanks for your answer
